# Need some advice on Phusion/Passenger setup

Tags: django, passenger

Okay, so.. I've never used this set of programs, so please be nice.
I help a guy out with his hosted application on dreamhost.  I mostly edit some HTML and python.  However, it's pretty legacy and it's running phusion/passenger.  It's a django site, but I don't think it's "deployed correctly" with django.

Typically, I copy everything locally, make edits and run the application manually with something like: `python  manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --verbosity 3`
I then just copy over the changes.. However, some of the python modules are REALLY old. I wanted to try and update them.

When I update django in my dev environment the application works fine.
However, when I update django on the dreamhost environment the application bombs. (I do not have the exception handy)

So, I want to more accurately reproduce this environment.

I've built a docker container with apache, passenger, etc.

I'd like to figure out how to put this application into the passanger environment so I can reproduce the environment.  But I simple don't know how - and the amount of Googling i've done has not helped.